# Azure get access token via javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-rest-api

I'm trying to get an access token from Azure. I was following [this](https://blog.jongallant.com/2021/02/azure-rest-apis-postman-2021/) tutorial, but the thing is that the guy's using postman. It works for me in postman as well, but it fails in javascript and I don't understand why.

```
  function getAccessToken() {
    fetch(`${loginUrl}${tenantId}/oauth2/token`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
        resource: resource,
      })
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      });
  }
```

The credentials are good, i.e. the clientId, secret, tenantid etc.
I also tried in PowerShell and it worked:

```
Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Uri "$loginUrl$tenantId/oauth2/token" `
    -Method Post `
    -Body @{"grant_type"="client_credentials"; "resource" = $resource; "client_id" = $clientId; "client_secret" = $clientSecret }
```

But on js I get the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/myTenantId/oauth2/token' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I'm running this script in an HTML file for testing purposes at the moment.

Comment: In HTML file, when we directly call rest API from a different domain, we will get cors issue.  For more details, please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. Besides, if you want to get Azue AD token in HTML file, you can use msaljs to implement implicit flow to get token : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we directly call the rest api from a domain different from your website in the HTML page, we will get CORS issue. This is for safety reasons. For more details, please refer to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

So if you want to get Azure AD token in HTML page, I suggest you use package  msaljs to implement implicit flow to get token. The package has fixed cors issue. Regarding how to do that, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa).

Besides, if you still want to use client credentials flow to get token in your HTML page. You have two choices. One choice is to use proxy server. The proxy acts as an intermediary between a client and server. For future details about it, please refer to the [blog](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9#:%7E:text=Why%20was%20the%20CORS%20error,%3A%20cross%2Dsite%20request%20forgery.).